# Most effective directed speedlight diffusers?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting, studio-lighting, hotshoe-flash, diffusers

Since I have a wireless flash I figured I may as well get a tripod adapter and some sort of diffuser so I can supplement strobes, and especially use it off-camera at locations I wouldn't haul monolights.

What are the best options for balancing diffusion with light transmission from a flash?

The problem with a flash is that it starts out quite directed, so to begin with I'm assuming it's not well suited to umbrellas — either reflective or shoot-through.  Without taking advantage of reflector geometry I was thinking it would take two diffusion layers to smooth it out, but that's going to cut out a lot of its light, which is already its weak point.  But if I'm over-thinking this just let me know if there's a consensus on the best directed flash diffusers.

Comment: You might find 
[Does the wide-angle diffuser on a flash help reduce hotspots when used in a small softbox?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/48313/1943) to be useful, although it doesn't completely answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to diffusers you should be looking to use the same sizes as you would for monolights.  The flash tube of a monolight often isn't that much larger than the head of a speedlight and the size of the modifier is mainly what creates the effect.

This is echoed by the soft mods section in [Strobist blog's](http://strobist.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/without-reservation-recommended-gear.html) gear recommendations.  Strobist blog is highly respected by speedlight users and the article includes links to specific products which are more suitable for speedlights.

Answer (score 3):

Umbrellas work just fine with speedlights. The light from a speedlight is not too directed for that, especially if you use white umbrellas which will spread the light more or less independently of which direction it came from.

I will echo James's comment to check out Strobist.com for info on how to make good use of off-camera speedlights. The most useful info, IMO, is in his [Lighting 101](http://strobist.blogspot.dk/2006/03/lighting-101.html) series of articles.